# HTML5 Streaming a Live Video With WebSockets (Websocket sending the video frame as blob)

Tags: websocket, video-streaming

I want to make a live video streaming with WebSocket .
So Websocket sending message to the client as a blob .
I'm trying to get the message and make a live video in  element . I used MediaSource and SourceBuffer . But It didn't work . Anyone who knows anything or worked before with mediasource, I'm waiting for your response...

Comment: Why are you using WebSockets for this?  You can use regular HTTP.

Comment: @Brad, I think they're doing more of a Xoom live stream rather than a M3U8/HLS live stream.

Comment: @Bal10Man Not enough useful info to help you. What video format (what codec) did you send? Did your  MediaSource code ever work (with other files but not this one)? Not obvious if the _"But It didn't  work"_ problem is with your code or with the video data itself...